# Flutter Text widget proportions

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, text-widget

Is there any way to change size proportions for letters (words/texts) in Flutter?
Ideally, I need to have the ability to change the size of some Container, for example, and the Text child of this Container has to fill all the space from edge to edge, no matter what size proportions this container has. If the container has size 10*200 and the child of this Container is Text with "3", so three number has to be very thin/tall looking number. I hope it makes sense.

Pictures below are showing what I mean, approximately (don't look at the red background):

[image]
[image]

The first picture has, let's say, the proportion of 20*160 and the seconds on has the opposite (160*20).

Maybe there are some packages for that?

Comment: you can use transform() widget

Comment: Thanks @Milvintsiss! I completely forgot about the transform widget! Thanks a lot, you saved me an hour or two, I would try to make in in some weird way :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for people who might have the same questions, the transform widget will be something like that:

```
Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.identity()
    ..setEntry(0, 0, xProportion),
    ..setEntry(1, 1, yProportion),
  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
  child: Text("3"),
)
```